# How did mantras come to exist?

Tags: vedas, mantras, rishi

How did these people know about the powers of chanting mantras? Specifically how did they know what to say and what exactly they are.

Comment: It seems off-topic to me.. Here is my thoughts: How did these people know about the powers of chanting mantras? May be they might have experienced the power of mantra. Mantra, a divine sound that has been received or experienced by an adept in the state of spiritual absorption. Specifically how did they know what to say and what exactly they are.? Human brains evolved millions of years ago, no wonder they might adopt how to read and write in evolution.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below from Kamika Agama, Purva Pada (Verses 1-3, Chapter 2). Agamas are *shrutis* (just like vedas) revealed by Lord Shiva himself. So the point of questioning them does not arise.

[image]

The first stanza says there is no action is to be conducted without a mantra - be it tilling the land or regular worship.

Second stanza says there "manana" is the ability to know everything, and "trana" is liberation from samsara. Combining these two gives you "mantra"

The third stanza says mantra consists of two parts - vacya and vacaka. Vacya is form of the word, while vacaka is the deep meaning. These two are inseperable.

The Agamas contain details of even the minutest of activity you can think of, and the mantras to be chanted while carrying out those activites.